# Canvas Colour Change Function Javascript - Drawing Tool

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am building a drawing tool with the canvas function and am trying to allow the user to change the colour of the line they are using.
I followed a video tut but i think JS might of updated since it was made.

If you could help me out for my uni project that would be incredible !
Thank You!!!

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 60;
canvas.height = 400;

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let draw_color = "black";
let draw_width = "2";
let is_drawing = false;

function change_color() {
draw_color = element.style.background;
}

// Allows for the pen to go up and down without constantly drawing //
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stop, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);


// Functions that allow the drawing to actually happen //
function start(event){
    is_drawing = true;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                  event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
   event.preventDefault();
}

function draw(event) {
    if (is_drawing) {
        context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop)
             context.strokestyle = draw_color;
             context.linewidth = draw_width;
             context.lineCap = "round";
             context.lineJoin = "round";
             context.stroke();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}

// Functions that allow the drawing to actually stop //
function stop(event) {
if (is_drawing) {
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    is_drawing = false;
}
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should've written 'strokeStyle' and 'lineWidth' instead of 'strokestyle' and 'linewidth'.
It's called camel case.